# Map layers disappear when new projection is defined

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I am using ArcGIS Pro to define projections of 2 different layers (1 unknown, 1 WGS84) from a 3rd layer's correct projection (MGI Austria GK M31). I have also transformed the map's projection from WGS84 to MGI Austria GK M31.

My problem is: all layers *seemingly* have the correct projections and transformations, but the 2 layers that had to be defined to MGI Austria GK M31 have now disappeared from my map. Furthermore, the layer with the unknown SRS does not even show its polygon image anymore when I zoom to layer.

Comment: Don't ever set the CRS of layers, always correctly reproject them.

Comment: 1. Use Project tool to convert the WGS84 layer to MGI Austria GK M31. 2. You need to identify what CRS the unknown layer is actually in and use the Define Projection tool to set that first. Then you can reproject it using the Project Tool.